# Probability Theorem

Tags: probability, statistics

So I have this theorem which I understand but proving it is more than weird to me. So it is:

> If $E_1$ and $E_2$ are subsets of $S$ and $E_1\subseteq E_2$ then $P(E_1)\le P(E_2)$

Which I understand and it is somewhat intuitively logical, but here's the proof:

> $E_2=E_1\cup(E_1\cap E_2)$

I understand that, but

> $E_1$ is mutually exclusive to $E_1\cap E_2$

Why is it so? If we have two events so that $E_1$ is a subset of $E_2$ then they must have mutual events, so how come is it that their intersection is mutually exclusive to $E_1$?

What I think of is that $E_2$ is equal to what is to union of what is in $E_1$ and what is outside of $E_1$ but in $E_2$ which is absent in $E_1$, but $E_1\cap E_2$ is basically whatever is in both, which to me sounds wrong, is it that the theorem stated above is wrong? (Our universities notes tend to be extremely inaccurate sometimes.)

So my reasoning is that it should be:

> $E_2 = E_1 \cup (E_2$ \ $E_1)$

Which is the event 2 is equal to event 1 in union with the relative complement of event 2 and event 1.

A visualization would be extremely helpful!
Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Why do you say that "$E_1$ is mutually exclusive to $E_1\cap E_2$"?  It is incorrect.

Comment: Exactly what I was wondering, I took it from my class lecture notes given to us in a form of a PDF. It sounds highly unlikely to me that this is true.

Comment: Shouldn't it be that E2 = E1 U (E2 \ E1) ??

Comment: "E2 = E1 union (E1 intersection E2)" is incorrect, too.

Comment: @ChrisDobkowski, you are correct that $E_2=E_1\cup(E_2\backslash E_1)$.  Could you provide a link to your class lecture notes?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche yes of course, here you are: http://www.computing.dcu.ie/~jhorgan/chapter5slides.pdf and scroll to the *theorem 3* which doesn't even have a name haha... And thank you a lot!

Comment: Oh wow... i opened the notes in the browser and suddenly I can see that it says E1 complement... it's fault of my soda PDF reader. :P

Comment: You are correct.  Do you still want me to answer in more detail?

Comment: Yes please, if possible, I would also like to select it as correct answer so you can earn some credit for it :D
But still, complement of E1 intersection E2 is weird to me, if it is true than could you explain that to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notes you linked to has the following proof:

> $E_2=E_1\cup(\overline{E_1}\cap E_2)$.  Now, since $E_1$ and $\overline{E_1}\cap E_2$ are mutually exclusive, $P(E_2)=P(E_1)+P(\overline{E_1}\cap E_2)\ge P(E_1)$ since $P(\overline{E_1}\cap E_2)\ge 0$ from Axiom 1.

As you noticed, your PDF reader omitted the complement on $E_1$.

From your comment, it seems that you want the first statement of the proof clarified.  The drawing below shows $\overline{E_1}\cap E_2$.  Does it make things clearer now?

[image: (not E_1)int E_2]

Comment: Great! Thank you very very much! You are awesome! :)
And thank you for the Venn Diagram :D

Comment: One more thing, is there a name for this theorem? Since the name is missing in the notes :P

Comment: Wikipedia calls it monotonicity (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axioms_of_probability#Monotonicity).

Answer (score 1):

[This Venn diagram](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Discrete_Mathematics/Set_theory#Venn_Diagrams) will help you.

Comment: Oh great! Now everything is clear! :D
Thank you sir! :)

Comment: You are welcom! My pleasure.